# Control OpenVPN's publicly visible IP Address

Tags: openvpn

I would like to separate services on a host with two separate IP addresses. One IP should only be used for OpenVPN and will function as a gateway for connecting to other servers. On the other IP all kind of services are being served.

```
# /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 123.245.100.147
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    gateway 123.245.100.145
    up ip addr add 123.245.100.148/28 dev eth0

### OpenVPN IP
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.10.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The Problem I currently have is that I am not able to change the publicly visible OpenVPN IP address.
OpenVPN does listen on 123.245.100.147, but the host is using 123.245.100.148 for outbound traffic apparently.

```
# Extract from /etc/openvpn/server.conf

# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
local 123.245.100.147
[...]


# opened ports

root@srv02 /etc/openvpn $ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2425/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 123.245.100.148:80      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10386/apache2   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13836/proftpd: (acc
tcp        0      0 123.245.100.148:22      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10170/sshd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2868/exim4      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2868/exim4      
udp        0      0 123.245.100.147:1194    0.0.0.0:*                           12477/openvpn
```

Connecting to the OpenVPN is not an issue at all. All I wanna do is connect to 123.245.100.147 and use 123.245.100.147 as the source address to other destinations while having other services listen on 123.245.100.148. The outgoing IP for the services running on 123.245.100.148 does not matter.

Current situation is however, client connects to 123.245.100.147 but externally visible address is 123.245.100.148.

Thanks for your help.

**Solution**

As mentioned by Zoredache there was indeed an iptables rule which I have not seen when looking at `iptables -nL`

```
root@srv02 ~ $ iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

However, revealing all applied rules with `iptables-save` did actually show the problem.

```
root@srv02 ~ $ iptables-save 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Wed Apr 22 23:30:08 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [221621:230332072]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [130716:101992043]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [253503:132488010]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 22 23:30:08 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Wed Apr 22 23:30:08 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1370874:86580150]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1025247:61032269]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1408751:103150160]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1408759:103150991]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 123.245.100.148
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 22 23:30:08 2015
```

Comment: The correct way to see the **nat** table is `iptables -nL -t nat`.  You don't need to use iptables-save for that.

Answer (score 1):

What does your firewall look like?  OpenVPN doesn't have anything to do with source address of outgoing packets from routed VPN clients.  You almost certainly have some kind of SNAT/MASQ rule in your iptables/firewall config.  You need to change that.  Or add an additional rule for your OpenVPN clients.  The port OpenVPN listens on has nothing to do with routed VPN traffic.

Comment: Just did look at iptables -nL, which was empty. iptables-save revealed the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I saw, I even just added a comment about how to properly display the nat table.